# html5 canvas large sprite sheet image animation performance optimization

Tags: animation, canvas, html5-canvas, sprite-sheet

I am using the method from 
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/
to render sprite sheet animation on canvas

and it works fine mostly

But when the sprite sheet image is  **large**, (30000*500, 60 frames png file in my case) the performance is so bad especially on Android webview.

I think the image resource tooks too much memory, but how do I optimize its memory usage ? I've tried compress the image by "ImageOptim", but it didn't make any noticeable difference.

Can someone give me some advices about performance optimization when rendering large sprite sheet on canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageBitmaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap).

Your image is probably too big to be held in the graphic cards memory, this means that every time it has to be moved there again, which may makes things really slow indeed.

ImageBitmap objects allow to keep the raw bitmap data ready to be used by the GPU with no extra.
So at init, you'd prepare your ImageBitmaps and throw away the full image. 
Now only small bitmaps ready to be put would get passed to the GPU.

```js
async function initSprites( img, sprite_width = img.width, sprite_height = img.height ) {
  // you would have to make the sprite factory logic based on your actual spritesheet,
  // here Im using a simple fixed-size grid from wikimedia
  const sprites = [];
  for( let y = 0; y < img.height; y += sprite_height) {
    for( let x = 0; x < img.width; x += sprite_width ) {
      sprites.push(
        await createImageBitmap( img, x, y, sprite_width, sprite_height )
      );
    }
  }
  return sprites;
}
async function loadImage( url ) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  await new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    img.onload = (e) => res( img );
    img.onerror = rej;
    img.src = url;
  } );
  return img;
}

async function init() {
  const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/SpriteSheet.png";
  const FPS = 10;
  const sprite_width = 132;
  const sprite_height = 97;
  
  // we don't keep any reference to the Image
  const sprites = await initSprites( await loadImage( url ), sprite_width, sprite_height );
  
  const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
  const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
  const frame_time = 1000 / FPS;
  let sprite_index = 0;
  let lastTime = performance.now();
  
  requestAnimationFrame( update );
  
  function update( t ) {
    if( t - lastTime > frame_time ) {
      lastTime = t;
      sprite_index = (sprite_index + 1) % sprites.length;
      draw();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( update );
  }
  
  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    // we just reproduce the original spritesheet
    // but animated
    let inner_index = 0;
    for(let y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      for( let x = 0; x < 4; x ++ ) {
        inner_index ++;
        const index = (sprite_index + inner_index) % sprites.length;
        const sprite = sprites[ index ];
        ctx.drawImage( sprite, x * sprite_width, y * sprite_height );
      }
    }
  }
}

// for Safari and IE
monkeyPatchCreateImageBitmap();

init().catch( console.error );


// a very poor monkey patch, only allowing HTMLImageElement as source
// returns an HTMLCanvasElement
function monkeyPatchCreateImageBitmap() {
  if( typeof window.createImageBitmap === 'undefined' ) {
    window.createImageBitmap = monkeyPatch;
  }
  function monkeyPatch( img, sx = 0 , sy = 0, sw = img.width, sh = img.height ){
    const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    canvas.width = sw;
    canvas.height = sh;
    canvas.getContext( '2d' )
      .drawImage( img, sx, sy, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh );
    canvas.close = (e) => canvas.width = 0;
    return Promise.resolve( canvas );
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="528" height="291"></canvas>
```

Comment: my issue is when the sprite sheet image is too large, it consumes too much memory, which make the animation looks laggy, are there some practice about memory optimization?

Comment: Even using ImageBitmaps? Your image data should just get freed after that. Also, be sure to only init the sprites you'll actually be using, if e.g you make a multi-level game, no need to load the lvl99 boss at lvl1. Then, what can make the animation laggy is moving the data in memory, that's what this answer concentrates on. That a lot of memory is being used in itself should not cause lags. However, the more memory you use for your assets, the less you'll have available for your logic, so be sure to optimize there. Finally, the only way to optimize further your assets is to reduce their size.